# Send BNB or ETH to get back token automatically Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am working on a contract with openzeppelin and remix ide.
In this contract I have written a fallback function to get ether from consumer and send them the token automatically.
here is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelincontracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20{
    address public owner;
    uint256 public value;
    constructor() ERC20("MtToken", "TKN"){
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(owner, 1000000 ether);
        increaseAllowance(owner, 1000000 ether);
    }

    fallback() external payable{
        value += msg.value;
        if(msg.value > (0.01 ether)){
            transferFrom(owner, msg.sender, (1000 ether));
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to send BNB or ETH in test net to get back the token transaction fails.

Comment: Replicating your problem in remix results in transactions processed successfully. I replaced your import statement with `import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";`. However, consider `receive() external payable` over `fallback() external payable`.

Comment: @norym I have test it as you said but again it fails. Which network have you used?